# Program not displaying everything it's supposed to

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am writing an inventory program for a book store that is comprised of two classes and multiple methods within these classes.

The method I'm having the most trouble with is my purchase() method which is supposed to interactively process a purchase, update the array after the purchase, and display totals for items sold and total amount of money made that day.

The method is supposed to follow these 10 steps:

1. Ask the user to enter the ISBN number of the book they'd like to purchase.
2. Search the array for the object that contains that ISBN.
3. If the ISBN isn't found in the array, display a message stating that we don't have that book.
4. If the ISBN is found but the number of copies is 0, display a message saying the book is out of stock.
5. If the ISBN is found and the number of copies is greater than 0, ask the user how many copies they'd like to purchase.
6. If the number they enter is greater than the number of copies of that book in the array, display a message stating that and ask them to enter another quantity.
7. When they enter a 0 for the ISBN, the Scanner is supposed to close
8. Once the purchase is complete I need to update the array by subtracting the number of copies of that particular book that was purchased.
9. Print the updated array.
10. Display a count of how many books were purchased, and how much money was made from the purchase.

But as my code is written, after the Program prompts me to enter an ISBN, nothing happens, it just continually lets me enter numbers with no additional output.

Here is the code I have for this method. I'm pretty sure it's probably an issue with my loop as I'm not very good with looping. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static Book[] purchase(Book[] books) {
    int itemsSold = 0;
    double totalMade = 0;
    double price;
    int copies; 
    String isbn;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int desiredCopies = 0;
    int index;
    double total = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter the ISBN number of the book you would like to purchase: ");
    String desiredIsbn = input.next();

    for (index = 0; index < books.length; index++) {
        if (books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && books[index].getCopies() > 0) {
            System.out.println("How many copies of this book would you like to purchase?");

            if (!books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn))
                System.out.println("We do not have that book in our inventory.");
            if (books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && books[index].getCopies() == 0)
                System.out.println("That book is currently out of stock.");

            desiredCopies = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (desiredCopies > books[index].getCopies())
            System.out.println("We only have " + books[index].getCopies() + "in stock. Please select another quantity: ");

        desiredCopies = input.nextInt();
        books[index].setCopies(books[index].getCopies() - desiredCopies);

        if (input.next().equals(0)) 
            System.out.println("Thank you for your purchase, your order total is: $" + total);

        input.close();

        total = books[index].getPrice() * desiredCopies;
        itemsSold += desiredCopies;
        totalMade += total;

        System.out.print(books[index]);
        System.out.println("We sold " + itemsSold + " today.");
        System.out.println("We made $" + totalMade + "today.");
    }

    return books;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the results of your attempts to debug your problem.

Comment: One other unsolicited suggestion -- your heuristic of coming here **before** attempting to debug the problem will hurt you in the long run, as it will prevent you from learning the critical techniques and thinking involved in debugging your program. I would suggest you approach future problems differently, using a debugger to analyze the problem *before* coming here, and then if you still don't have a solution, post the results of your debug attempts. Else, you will only learn to ask questions here and not how to solve your own problems. OK, I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are not matching every possible condition

Your `if` statements aren't covering all the possible permutations of conditions apparently.

You should use always use an `if/else if/else` block to make sure you cover all your conditions. Outside this there is absolutely **no way** for anyone to provide any actual solution with so little to go on.

#### Also

`Scanner` and `StringTokenizer` are two of the worst designed classes in the JDK outside `Date` and `Calendar`. They cause endless trouble for new people and are avoided by the veterans.